# How can I make my openAM SDK app know where to find OpenAM server?

Tags: sdk, openam, forgerock

I am writing a complemental service for OpenAM for some features not available as RESTful services in default server. I am using OpenAM Client SDK (12 or 13). I get the folloing error:

```
DebugConfiguration:07/03/2017 04:13:12:530 PM IRDT: 
Thread[main,5,main]
'/debugconfig.properties' isn't valid, the default configuration will be used instead: Can't find the configuration file

'/debugconfig.properties'.
amAuthContext:07/03/2017 04:13:12:564 PM IRDT: Thread[main,5,main]: 
TransactionId[unknown]
 ERROR: Failed to obtain auth service url from server: null://null:null
 amNaming:07/03/2017 04:13:12:573 PM IRDT: Thread[main,5,main]: 
TransactionId[unknown]
ERROR: Failed to initialize naming service
java.lang.Exception: Cannot find Naming Service URL.
at com.iplanet.services.naming.WebtopNaming.getNamingServiceURL(WebtopNaming.java:1254)
at com.iplanet.services.naming.WebtopNaming.initializeNamingService(WebtopNaming.java:272)
at com.iplanet.services.naming.WebtopNaming.updateNamingTable(WebtopNaming.java:1149)
at com.iplanet.services.naming.WebtopNaming.getNamingProfile(WebtopNaming.java:1070)
at com.iplanet.services.naming.WebtopNaming.getServiceAllURLs(WebtopNaming.java:494)
at com.sun.identity.authentication.AuthContext.login(AuthContext.java:654)
at com.sun.identity.authentication.AuthContext.login(AuthContext.java:584)
at com.sun.identity.authentication.AuthContext.login(AuthContext.java:386)
at MainKt.realmLogin(Main.kt:56)
at MainKt.main(Main.kt:144)

IdRepoSampleUtils: Failed to start login for default authmodule
Exception in thread "main" 
com.sun.identity.authentication.spi.AuthLoginException: Failed to create new Authentication Context: null
at com.sun.identity.authentication.AuthContext.login(AuthContext.java:657)
at com.sun.identity.authentication.AuthContext.login(AuthContext.java:584)
at com.sun.identity.authentication.AuthContext.login(AuthContext.java:386)
at MainKt.realmLogin(Main.kt:56)
at MainKt.main(Main.kt:144)
```

The main error is SDk does not find STS server url. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution with checking the Example SDK client. The solution is to use Java's well-knwon properties file. There is a AMConfig.properties in there which the SDK jar automatically tries to extract values from it. For the format of the file we can refer to Oracle OpenSSO, and use the AMConfig.properties.template within the OpenAM example client application.